# How to change the produced type of a Rx Observable from int to double?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following code:

```
var timer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
timer.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, ()=>Console.WriteLine("Completed"));
```

which produces integers from 0 to ...

But the Question is why integers?
Is it possible to produce doubles in the From 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 without extra calculation?

Comment: It seems it will generate `long`s rather than `int`s. You can take a peek at the source code here - https://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/Timer.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rx Timer will generate incremental long values, that you can further transform into something else by using a Select statement.
In your case if you want to obtain a list of double values you can simply change your timer declaration like this:

```
var timer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Select(i => i / 10.0);
timer.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, ()=>Console.WriteLine("Completed"));
```

I don't think you can do that without adding a select operator, as it will require to rewrite the Timer generator function, which should not be that much difficult, but can be tricky.